# Adding data into SQLite database from another class in android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to add a simple int count which is set to count++ everytime a player wins it will increment by 1. I am trying to add this int count inside my SQLite Database. But I have no Idea how I can do that, the database is in one class, and my int value is in another class, How can I add the int inside the database. I have created a addScores method inside my class:

Database Code:

```
public class Database {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id"; 
public static final String KEY_NAME = "number_of_wins"; 

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HIGHSCORES"; 
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE= "Total_Wins"; 
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private DBHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

  private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " INTEGER);"
                    );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
public Database(Context context) {
    ourContext = context;
}

public Database open() {
    ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public Cursor getScores() {
    return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE, null); //No Parameter
}
}
```

Someother Class:

```
int count =0;
count++;
//Adding HighScore to Database
        public void addScore() {

        }
```

How do I add the int count inside my database? I am trying to add it in the column number_of_wins?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a value in the database using something like this.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("number_of_wins", counter);
id = ourDatabase.insertOrThrow("Total_Wins", null, values);
```

Create a method in your database class and add/modify this code, and finally call this new method from 'SomeOther' class.

Comment: what is Id?, do I have to create a new method in database class?, and how do I reference "counter" because it is saying it cannot be resolved?

Comment: id is the rowid of the newly inserted record. `counter` is the number of wins, just replace it with your variable.

Comment: Do i put this in my some other class or database class?

Comment: It's in my answer... in the database class!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple DBHelper that should work for you and get you started, create an instance of this and you should be able to add a score into your database, However I highly recommend you read the tutorial in comment, and really figure out how it works. So from here you should be able to complete all other `CRUD` operations.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "HIGHSCORES";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "TotalWins";

    // The keys
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_SCORE = "NumberOfWins";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_SCORE + " INTEGER);"
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Careful with this!
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addScore(int score) {
        // Get a writable database handle
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        // Put the coun into a ContentValues object, with correct key
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();    
        values.put(KEY_SCORE, score);

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);

        // Closing database connection
        db.close();     
    }
}
```

Comment: which class do I put this method in?

Comment: This method needs to be placed in your db helper class.

Comment: Also remember when you call `getWritableDatabase()` the `onUpgrade()` is called and your `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);` may be dangerous if you want to persist any data.

Comment: Oh one thing, check out this link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ 
it has a really good tutorial on how to get started with SQLite databases, it's really describing and easy to follow

Comment: I am getting an error on getWritable it says I need to create this method?

Comment: it should be `getWritableDatabase()`, also are you calling that inside your DBHelper?

Comment: yeah its getWritableDatabase()´ and I just added the method and its not in my DBHelper its right after my getScores method, If I put it in my DBhelper I get a warning that the method is not locally used, so but the error on the getWritableDatabase() dissapears

Comment: @user3322960, made an update to my answer that should make it all clearer

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have the unique id for the particular count you'd like to increase. In that case, I'd write the following method inside of the Database class and call it when the count should increase.

```
public void addScore(long id) {
    ourDatabase.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s=%s+1 WHERE %s=%d",
        DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME, KEY_NAME, KEY_ID, id));
}
```